# Creating new device in AVD Manager

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I've tried to create new device in AVD Manager but have this problem: Failed to load. But I couldn't find the same theme.

here is my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lowF1.png).

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it cannot find `armeabi` system image from default folder so you have to install the `armeabi` from `sdk` manager.

Go to tools --> android --> skdmanager and install it.

If it helps you please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for help!! I've downloaded AMR ABI and Android 4.4(API 19) and now it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not have the Android-19 sdk installed. Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager and check to see if Android 4.4 (API 19) is installed.

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html